# Mantel-Haenszel method issue with meta package

Tags: r

I'm working on chapter 4.2.3.1.4 of "Doing Meta Analysis with R: A Hands-On Guide" where I have to import "DepressionMortality" data set and use the `metabin()` function to calculate the individual/pooled risk ratio and 95% CI.

The function is supposed to use Mantel-Haenszel method and I followed the textbook as written; all the results came out as the textbook said but the "details on meta-analytical method" section shows that it's inverse variance method, not Mantel-Haenszel.

I've updated RStudio to the most recent version and tried again, but the same issue arises.

Any idea how I can fix this? Where is this issue coming from?

The details indicate that it's Inverse variance method, not Mantel-Haenszel

[image]

Here's the code:

```
> data(DepressionMortality)
> glimpse(DepressionMortality)
Rows: 18
Columns: 6
$ author  <chr> "Aaroma et al., 1994", "Black et al., 1998", "Bruce et al., 1989", "Bruce et al., 1…
$ event.e <dbl> 25, 65, 5, 26, 32, 1, 24, 15, 15, 173, 37, 41, 29, 61, 15, 21, 10, 31
$ n.e     <dbl> 215, 588, 46, 67, 407, 44, 60, 61, 29, 1015, 105, 120, 258, 388, 211, 237, 48, 615
$ event.c <dbl> 171, 120, 107, 1168, 269, 87, 200, 437, 227, 250, 66, 9, 24, 34, 73, 67, 36, 1468
$ n.c     <dbl> 3088, 1901, 2479, 3493, 6256, 1520, 882, 2603, 853, 3375, 409, 54, 1490, 1257, 1366…
$ country <chr> "Finland", "USA", "USA", "USA", "Sweden", "USA", "Canada", "Netherlands", "Finland"…

> m.bin = metabin(event.e = event.e, n.e = n.e, event.c = event.c, n.c = n.c, studlab = author, data = DepressionMortality, sm = "RR", method = "MH", MH.exact = TRUE, comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE, method.tau = "PM", hakn = TRUE, title = "Depression and Mortality")

> summary(m.bin)
```

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).